# amend all comments of all commits of a repository

Tags: azure-devops, libgit2sharp

I'm moving our on premise tfs repositories to visualstudio online. In the process I'd prefer to convert everything to git.
I found this (*) post online and everything works. But now I would like to use `libgit2sharp` to amend all the comments so to point to the correct work items.

I've cobbled together a bit of code that should do the trick:

```
Dictionary<string,string> links; //contains all links between new and old workitems, keys: old workitems, values: new workitems

using (var repo = new Repository(@"D:\gittfs\testproject"))
{
    foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
    {
        var commitMessage = commit.Message;
        var regex = new Regex(@"#[0-9]*");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(commitMessage))
        {
            string newId;
            if (links.TryGetValue(match.ToString(), out newId))
            {
                commitMessage = commitMessage.Replace(match.ToString(), newId);
            }
        }

        var c = repo.Commit(commitMessage, new CommitOptions { AmendPreviousCommit = true });
    }
}
```

This code runs without a problem and if I compare `c.Message` with `commit.Message`, I can see several of these being replaced. The problem is that after the program has ran, none of the amended commits are in the repository. So I think I'm still doing something wrong?

(*)https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week02mar2014/migrating-a-tfs-tfvc-based-team-project-to-a-git-team-project-retaining-as-much-source-and-work-item-history-as-possible/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might rather be after some **[git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)** like feature.

LibGit2Sharp exposes this through the **[HistoryRewriter](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Core/HistoryRewriter.cs)** type.

You can peek at the **[FilterBranchFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FilterBranchFixture.cs)** test suite for inspiration.

Comment: @elangelo Added links

Answer (score 0):

following code did the trick for me. thnx nulltoken!

```
 var rewriteHistoryOptions = new RewriteHistoryOptions()
            {
                CommitHeaderRewriter = commit =>
                {
                    var commitMessage = commit.Message;
                    bool stuffreplaced = false;
                    var r = new Regex(@"#[0-9]*\ ");
                    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(commit.Message))
                    {
                        string value;
                        if (links.TryGetValue(match.ToString().TrimEnd(), out value))
                        {
                            commitMessage = commitMessage.Replace(match.ToString().Trim(), value);
                            Console.WriteLine(commit.Id + ": " + match.ToString() + " replaced by " + value);
                            stuffreplaced = true;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (stuffreplaced)
                    {
                        return CommitRewriteInfo.From(commit, message: commitMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return CommitRewriteInfo.From(commit);
                    }
                }
            };

            repo.Refs.RewriteHistory(rewriteHistoryOptions, repo.Commits);
```